# Metadata extraction of Thoughtspot

Tags: graphql, metadata

I need to extract metadata from thoughtspot .How can I do it by using Python Parser?

I am doing discovery part of thoughtspot on how to extract metadata. What are the steps to be followed to extract metadata through python parser and Graph QL.